# convert html to pdf in ruby script only with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: ruby, rubygems, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I know already pdfkit and wiked_pdf. pdfkit does not generate as I expect pdf from a remote web page.

Therefore I'd like to run **wkhtmltopdf** command in from within a ruby script as I do in the terminal.

In the script I've:

`%x[wkhtmltopdf "http://www.radiozamaneh.com/67671" "./kaka.pdf"]`

But the command is not executed. How should I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ` command is not executed` what is the error u are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the way you described:

```
%x[wkhtmltopdf "http://www.radiozamaneh.com/67671" "./kaka.pdf"] 
Loading page (1/2)
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)                     ] 38%
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)=============>       ] 88%
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)==============>      ] 89%
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)==============>      ] 89%
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)===============>     ] 90%
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)===============>     ] 90%
Printing pages (2/2)                                               
QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
Done                                                           
 => ""
```

So, obvious questions:

1. Do you have this program installed in your box?
2. The user that is running rails have the binary on its $PATH variable?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I initially tried it in ubuntu 12.10 which was not working while running the ruby script without any error message. but on my os x machine I've the ouput as you have. Also I don't have any rails instance.